# Dynamic cdkDragBoundary in Angular Material

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have a requirement wherein I am making nested drag and drop components using Angular Material.
So I have to restrict boundaries.

```
<ul cdkDropList [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="listIds">
   <li *ngFor="let item of array" cdkDrag>  ///item = {name: 'Adam', children: [...etc]}
        ....some work here
        <ng-container *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
            /// call the <ul> again recursively
        </ng-container>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Things are fine, but I'd like to restrict boundaries, so I added dynamic class to `ul`,

```
<ul cdkDropList [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="listIds" class="{{item.componentGuid}}"> 
/// class becomes some guid, eg: class="asd-123-qwe"
```

Want to use same class to `li` drag,

```
<li *ngFor="let item of array" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=""> 
 //this takes string like,    cdkDragBoundary="here class name given in ul",
```

if `ul` had class `test-boundary`,

```
<ul cdkDropList [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="listIds" class="test-boundary" >,
```

then `li` would be,

```
<li cdkDragBoundary=".test-boundary" cdkDrag>
```

But if `ul` had a dynamic class,

```
eg:class="{{item.componentGuid}}, which will resolve to 
   class="asd-123-qwe", then how do I add that to cdkDragBoundary??
```

Things I tried.

```
<li [cdkDragBoundary]="item.componentGuid" and few others.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the dot as well, because it will be handled as a query selector

```
<li [cdkDragBoundary]="'.' + item.componentGuid" cdkDrag>
```

Also when binding to a class, it's better to use `ngClass`:

```
[ngClass]="item.componentGuid"
```

Comment: Can't bind to 'cdkDragBoundary' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. 
cdkDragBoundary comes from angular material, giving boundary restrictions, can't substitute that with class.

Comment: @MichaelPhilips well, you do need to add the `cdkDrag` directive to the li

Comment: Tried that, same issue :(

Comment: @MichaelPhilips why do you want to restrict the boundary to a certain item. `item.componentGuid` should not even available at the `<ul>` level.